# How to change matrix column type in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix and I want to change the fifth column type from character into numeric but I can not. I have tried this:

```
test1[,5] <- as.numeric(test1[,5])
```

but again the column class is character not numeric. What should I do?
Thank you

Comment: You can only have one datatype in a matrix.

Comment: @Marius Actually I need to order my matrix based on this column but I need to order based on numeric view not characteric. Is there a way?

Comment: Try `test1[order(as.numeric(test1[, 5])), ]`.

Comment: @flodel yes thanks it works.I spend lots of time to change the column type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like @Marius said, a matrix can only hold one data type. You could convert your matrix into a data.frame since data.frames can hold a different data type for each of their columns. The functions for converting from and back are `as.data.frame` and `as.matrix`. You'll then be able to apply the column conversion code you posted to a data.frame.

However, you mentioned in a comment that your ultimate goal was to reorder your matrix based on the values of a coerced column. You don't need to coerce the column in-place before reordering your matrix, you can do all that on the fly with:

```
test1[order(as.numeric(test1[, 5])), ]
```