# How can I convert specific columns to the numeric type in a matrix (in r)?

Tags: r, string, matrix, type-conversion, numeric

I have the following matrix :

```
      Type   Tenor Frequency Rate      
 [1,] "SWAP" "1"   "1"       "-0.0048" 
 [2,] "SWAP" "2"   "1"       "-0.00334"
 [3,] "SWAP" "3"   "1"       "-0.00221"
 [4,] "SWAP" "4"   "1"       "-0.00135"
 [5,] "SWAP" "5"   "1"       "-0.00051"
 [6,] "SWAP" "6"   "1"       "0.00022" 
 [7,] "SWAP" "7"   "1"       "9e-04"   
 [8,] "SWAP" "8"   "1"       "0.00156" 
 [9,] "SWAP" "9"   "1"       "0.002155"
[10,] "SWAP" "10"  "1"       "0.002787"
```

But I need to do binary operations on some of these values, therefore I need to convert the columns "Tenor", "Frequency", and "Rate" to numeric.

I tried using this function : apply(input_matrix, 2, as.numeric)
which works and it gives me this :

```
      Type Tenor Frequency      Rate
 [1,]   NA     1         1 -0.004800
 [2,]   NA     2         1 -0.003340
 [3,]   NA     3         1 -0.002210
 [4,]   NA     4         1 -0.001350
 [5,]   NA     5         1 -0.000510
 [6,]   NA     6         1  0.000220
 [7,]   NA     7         1  0.000900
 [8,]   NA     8         1  0.001560
 [9,]   NA     9         1  0.002155
[10,]   NA    10         1  0.002787
```

But as soon as I insert a string in the first column with my for loop :

```
for(row in 1:nrow(input_matrix)) {
  input_matrix[row, 1] <- "SWAP";
}
```

it converts back ALL the values in the matrix to strings :

```
      Type   Tenor Frequency Rate      
 [1,] "SWAP" "1"   "1"       "-0.0048" 
 [2,] "SWAP" "2"   "1"       "-0.00334"
 [3,] "SWAP" "3"   "1"       "-0.00221"
 [4,] "SWAP" "4"   "1"       "-0.00135"
 [5,] "SWAP" "5"   "1"       "-0.00051"
 [6,] "SWAP" "6"   "1"       "0.00022" 
 [7,] "SWAP" "7"   "1"       "9e-04"   
 [8,] "SWAP" "8"   "1"       "0.00156" 
 [9,] "SWAP" "9"   "1"       "0.002155"
[10,] "SWAP" "10"  "1"       "0.002787"
```

So I can't do operations on it.

How can I convert only specific columns to numeric ?

I also tried `apply(input_matrix[,2:4], 2, as.numeric)` but it only returns the last 3 columns.

Bonus question : why does it have this effect (converting back ALL the values in the matrix to strings) ?

Comment: Matrices are an extension of vectors in R, but with dimensions, so they can only have one type. You would need a data frame which is an extension of a list to hold columns with different types. Read more [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change matrix column type in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858471/how-to-change-matrix-column-type-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comment @caldwellst I learned that it's not possible to have different types in a matrix, but that I could convert my matrix into a dataframe.

So with I created my matrix the exact same way as before but I didn't put any values in the first column, so I had this :

```
     Type Tenor Frequency     Rate
[1,]   NA     1         1 -0.00480
[2,]   NA     2         1 -0.00334
[3,]   NA     3         1 -0.00221
[4,]   NA     4         1 -0.00135
[5,]   NA     5         1 -0.00051
[6,]   NA     6         1  0.00022
```

Then with `input_df = as.data.frame(input_matrix)` I converted it to a dataframe and only then inserted the strings into the first column :

```
for(row in 1:nrow(input_df)) {
  input_df[row, 1] <- "SWAP";
}
```

Now I have this dataframe with numerics in the last 3 columns :

```
  Type Tenor Frequency     Rate
1 SWAP     1         1 -0.00480
2 SWAP     2         1 -0.00334
3 SWAP     3         1 -0.00221
4 SWAP     4         1 -0.00135
5 SWAP     5         1 -0.00051
6 SWAP     6         1  0.00022
```